# Excel Ranking with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, ranking

[image]https://www.dropbox.com/s/05f82d5piw0pfd2/Book1.xls

Hello everyone, can anyone show me how to deal with above ranking issue that I try to solve.

What I like to have is only ranking Names Occurrence when Month = February and Item = Item 1, also, ignore all item 2 with what even names and months between it.

Also, since I have more records, if possible could you please tell me how to apply ranking to whole columns.

Currently I try to use

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2),--(C:C=C2),--(B:B=B2)--(D2=D:D))`
```

but looks like it doesn't work that way.

Comment: This question is better suited to SuperUser

Comment: Why don't you just use pivot table?

Comment: Shouldn't item 1/name 4 have a rank? (third from bottom) - I assume you are only ranking the first instance of each occurrence - do you want conventional ranking for those or "ranking without gaps"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a helper column in column E (which can later be hidden) that screens out the rows you want to exclude:

```
 =IF(AND(A2="Item 1",C2="February"),D2,"")
```

which would of course be copied down to the bottom of your data.

Then do the ranking in column F of the formula results in column E:

```
 =IFERROR(RANK(E2,E:E),"")
```

again copied down to the end of the data.

Comment: Got my upvote for `RANK` - was not familiar with this one!

Comment: Thank you... Mr.chuff...

Answer (score 1):

The SUMPRODUCT might look something like this.  I don't fully understand why you only rank 3 of those 18 items; this sumproduct ranks all 11 of the ITEM=1 MONTH=FEBRUARY rows [it also, separately, ranks the other rows, but you can just wrap this in an IF and suppress those].

```
=1+SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$18=A2)*($C$2:$C$18=C2)*($D$2:$D$18>D2))
```

Reading that again, I guess you are really overcalculating the D column (that seems to be the number of C showing up).  You could use COUNTIF to see if you are on the first row with that NAME, I think.